# How to add/merge multiple Ext.data.JsonStore together in ExtJS 3.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, javascript-framework, extjs3

I want to add/merge multiple Ext.data.JsonStore and array data to a single Ext.data.JsonStore.

Below the code -

```
Store1: function (s) {
         var tmp = [];
         var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
             autoDestroy: true,
             url: 'url1,
             root: 'rows', 
             listeners: {
                 load: {
                     fn: function (store, records, options) {
                         store.data.each(function (item, index, totalItems) {
                             tmp.push([item.data.Index, item.data.Method]);
                         });
                         s.loadData(tmp);
                     }
                 }
             },
             fields: ['Index','Method']
         });
         store.load();
     },
Store2: function (s) {
             var tmp = [];
             var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                 autoDestroy: true,
                 url: 'url2,
                 root: 'rows', 
                 listeners: {
                     load: {
                         fn: function (store, records, options) {
                             store.data.each(function (item, index, totalItems) {
                                 tmp.push([item.data.ID, item.data.Type]);
                             });
                             s.loadData(tmp);
                         }
                     }
                 },
                 fields: ['ID', 'Type']
             });
             store.load();
         },

Store3: function () {
             var tmpGuests = [];
             var partyInfo = Ext.getCmp('party-tree');

         var parties = partyInfo.root.childNodes;

         Ext.each(parties, function (party) {
             Ext.each(party.childNodes, function (guest) {
                 tmpGuests.push([guest.id, guest.text]);
             }, this);
         }, this);

         return tmpGuests;
     }
```

And Tried like this -

```
AllStore: function (s) {
         var tmp = [];
         var storeTest;
         storeTest = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
             autoDestroy: true,
             url: 'Url1,
             root: 'rows', 
             listeners: {
                 load: {
                     fn: function (store, records, options) {
                         store.data.each(function (item, index, totalItems) {
                             tmp.push([item.data.Index, item.data.Method]);
                         });
                         s.loadData(tmp);
                         Store2.loadData(records, true);
                     }
                 },
             },
             fields: ['ID', 'Type']
         });
         storeTest.load();
     }
```

Which is not working, also I need to add array data (Store3) too. How can this possible?

Im using extJS 3.4

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how robust your solution should be but you should be able to take advantage of the [add](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-add) and [getRange](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getRange) methods.

Assuming all the stores have been loaded you can do something like:

```
var allStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore();
allStore.add(store1.getRange());
allStore.add(store2.getRange());
//..
```

If they haven't been loaded yet you can add them with a common listener, something like this:

```
var allStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore(),
    addToAllStore = function(store) {
        allStore.add(store.getRange());
    }

    store1.on('load', addToAllStore);
    store2.on('load', addToAllStore);
    store3.on('load', addToAllStore);
```

Comment: +1 though you might want to unmonitor the load event once it's been added once.

Comment: @karlipoppins you can always add the `single:true` to the listener options is it is needed for the business logic.